# Key Error when try to plot graph on python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot a chart using Pandas, but when I enter my columns I get an error called key error. How can I fix this?

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("SWP0001.CSV")
print(dataset.head(-1))
dataset.plot(x='FREQUENCY', y=['Ls', 'Rs'])

plt.xlabel('X-axis label')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis label')
plt.title('Plot of 3 Columns')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Here is error

```
KeyError: 'FREQUENCY'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\KorGraph\korGraph2.py", line 8, in <module>
    dataset.plot(x='FREQUENCY', y=['Ls', 'Rs'])
  File "..\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 965, in __call__
    elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):
  File "..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3804, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'FREQUENCY'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is screenshoot of my pandas output

[image: Pandas output]

Comment: Please check if the CSV file headers has leading or trailing whitespaces

Comment: Post a sample from the first few lines in SWP0001.CSV

Comment: Use `dataset.columns = dataset.columns.str.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

With the screenshot along it is hard to diagnose the problem. The `KeyError` means that pandas cannot find your column. What could be happening is that there is a leading or trailing space in the name of your `FREQUENCY` column that makes is not a match to the string `FREQUENCY`.

Check `dataset.columns` to see the actual strings of your column names